# Get the delta between two timestamps

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python script that outputs the following below. How can I get the delta between two timestamps of the same mac. Having the first timestamp as a reference point and subtract the delta between two consecutive resetcount values for the same mac. Required output below.

```
Timestamp,Mac,ResetCount
1,2022-03-22 10:00:00,10:93:97:F6:5B:71,25
2,2022-03-22 10:00:00,10:93:97:F6:63:89,31
3,2022-03-22 10:17:23,10:93:97:F6:5B:71,25
4,2022-03-22 10:17:23,10:93:97:F6:63:89,35
5,2022-03-22 10:39:39,10:93:97:F6:5B:71,28
6,2022-03-22 10:39:39,10:93:97:F6:63:89,38
7,2022-03-22 10:59:52,10:93:97:F6:5B:71,28
8,2022-03-22 10:59:52,10:93:97:F6:63:89,40
```

Required output:

```
2022-03-22 10:17:23,10:93:97:F6:5B:71,0 (delta between lines 1 and 3)
2022-03-22 10:17:23,10:93:97:F6:63:89,4 (delta between lines 2 and 4)
2022-03-22 10:39:39,10:93:97:F6:5B:71,3 (delta between lines 3 and 5)
2022-03-22 10:39:39,10:93:97:F6:63:89,3 (delta between lines 4 and 6)
2022-03-22 10:59:52,10:93:97:F6:5B:71,0 (delta between lines 5 and 7)
2022-03-22 10:59:52,10:93:97:F6:63:89,2 (delta between lines 6 and 8)
```

PS:

This is my query in my python script.

```
select timestamp AS Timestamp,JSON_KEYS(qoeFlaps,"$.rgFM") AS Mac,JSON_EXTRACT(qoeFlaps,"$.rgFM.*") AS ResetCount from ptdata.qoe_cmts_details where timestamp between '2022-03-22 10:00:00' and '2022-03-22 11:00:00';
```

Output above

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
  select mac, timestamp, lag(timestamp) over (partition by mac order by timestamp) as last_timestamp
  from mytable
)
select mac, timestamp, last_timestamp, timestampdiff(minute, last_timestamp, timestamp) as diff
from cte;
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| mac               | timestamp           | last_timestamp      | diff |
+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| 10:93:97:F6:5B:71 | 2022-03-22 10:00:00 | NULL                | NULL |
| 10:93:97:F6:5B:71 | 2022-03-22 10:17:23 | 2022-03-22 10:00:00 |   17 |
| 10:93:97:F6:5B:71 | 2022-03-22 10:39:39 | 2022-03-22 10:17:23 |   22 |
| 10:93:97:F6:5B:71 | 2022-03-22 10:59:52 | 2022-03-22 10:39:39 |   20 |
| 10:93:97:F6:63:89 | 2022-03-22 10:00:00 | NULL                | NULL |
| 10:93:97:F6:63:89 | 2022-03-22 10:17:23 | 2022-03-22 10:00:00 |   17 |
| 10:93:97:F6:63:89 | 2022-03-22 10:39:39 | 2022-03-22 10:17:23 |   22 |
| 10:93:97:F6:63:89 | 2022-03-22 10:59:52 | 2022-03-22 10:39:39 |   20 |
+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
```

The window functions like `LAG()` and the CTE syntax requires MySQL 8.0, but this has been the current version of MySQL since 2018, so you should be using it by now.

Comment: thanks Bill, but our system is still using 5.7 and there's no way we can update that to 8.0. My SQL query from python script is select timestamp,JSON_KEYS(qoeFlaps," + "'" + "$.rgFM" + "'" + "),JSON_EXTRACT(qoeFlaps," + "'" + "$.rgFM.*" + "'" + ") from ptdata.qoe_cmts_details where timestamp between " + "'" + str(time0) + "'" + " and " + "'" + str(time1)

Comment: Okay, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure. why you omit some rows, as you wanted the delta of every
row.

but on MySQL 8 you can use window function in this case LAG() gets you the last value of the row.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `Timestamp` VARCHAR(19),
>   `Mac` VARCHAR(17),
>   `ResetCount` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`Timestamp`, `Mac`, `ResetCount`)
> VALUES
>   ('2022-03-22 10:00:00', '10:93:97:F6:5B:71', '25'),
>   ('2022-03-22 10:00:00', '10:93:97:F6:63:89', '31'),
>   ('2022-03-22 10:17:23', '10:93:97:F6:5B:71', '25'),
>   ('2022-03-22 10:17:23', '10:93:97:F6:63:89', '35'),
>   ('2022-03-22 10:39:39', '10:93:97:F6:5B:71', '28'),
>   ('2022-03-22 10:39:39', '10:93:97:F6:63:89', '38'),
>   ('2022-03-22 10:59:52', '10:93:97:F6:5B:71', '28'),
>   ('2022-03-22 10:59:52', '10:93:97:F6:63:89', '40');
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS(
> SELECT 
> `Timestamp`, `Mac`, `ResetCount`, LAG(`ResetCount`) OVER(PARTITION BY `Mac` ORDER BY `Timestamp`) lastcount
> FROM table1)
> SELECT `Timestamp`, `Mac`, IF ( lastcount IS NULL,0,ResetCount - lastcount ) mycount FROM CTE ORDER BY `Timestamp` ASC
> ```
>
> ```
> Timestamp           | Mac               | mycount
> :------------------ | :---------------- | ------:
> 2022-03-22 10:00:00 | 10:93:97:F6:5B:71 |       0
> 2022-03-22 10:00:00 | 10:93:97:F6:63:89 |       0
> 2022-03-22 10:17:23 | 10:93:97:F6:5B:71 |       0
> 2022-03-22 10:17:23 | 10:93:97:F6:63:89 |       4
> 2022-03-22 10:39:39 | 10:93:97:F6:5B:71 |       3
> 2022-03-22 10:39:39 | 10:93:97:F6:63:89 |       3
> 2022-03-22 10:59:52 | 10:93:97:F6:5B:71 |       0
> 2022-03-22 10:59:52 | 10:93:97:F6:63:89 |       2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f27341d21ed0158b9d32098cf2744b3c)*

## For mysql 5.7 this gets much more uglier

Thie fiorst selct shows only that it works, for your code you must use the second query

The order of the result is sorted by timestamp, but as you have the same timestamp for more than one mac, if you want another order you need to add what ever determines taht.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `Timestamp` VARCHAR(19),
>   `Mac` VARCHAR(17),
>   `ResetCount` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`Timestamp`, `Mac`, `ResetCount`)
> VALUES
>   ('2022-03-22 10:00:00', '10:93:97:F6:5B:71', '25'),
>   ('2022-03-22 10:00:00', '10:93:97:F6:63:89', '31'),
>   ('2022-03-22 10:17:23', '10:93:97:F6:5B:71', '25'),
>   ('2022-03-22 10:17:23', '10:93:97:F6:63:89', '35'),
>   ('2022-03-22 10:39:39', '10:93:97:F6:5B:71', '28'),
>   ('2022-03-22 10:39:39', '10:93:97:F6:63:89', '38'),
>   ('2022-03-22 10:59:52', '10:93:97:F6:5B:71', '28'),
>   ('2022-03-22 10:59:52', '10:93:97:F6:63:89', '40');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> `Timestamp`, mac, dif
> FROM
> (SELECT
> `Timestamp`,
> IF(@mac = `Mac`, `ResetCount` - @count, -1) as  dif,
> @count := `ResetCount` as Resetcount,
> @mac := `Mac` as mac
> FROM
> (SELECT `Timestamp`, `Mac`, `ResetCount` FROm  table1 ORDER BY `Mac`,`Timestamp`) t1
> ,(SELECT @mac := '', @count := 0) t2) t3
> WHERE dif >= 0
> ORDER BY  `Timestamp` ASC
> ```
>
> ```
> Timestamp           | mac               | dif
> :------------------ | :---------------- | --:
> 2022-03-22 10:17:23 | 10:93:97:F6:63:89 |   4
> 2022-03-22 10:17:23 | 10:93:97:F6:5B:71 |   0
> 2022-03-22 10:39:39 | 10:93:97:F6:63:89 |   3
> 2022-03-22 10:39:39 | 10:93:97:F6:5B:71 |   3
> 2022-03-22 10:59:52 | 10:93:97:F6:63:89 |   2
> 2022-03-22 10:59:52 | 10:93:97:F6:5B:71 |   0
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> `Timestamp`, mac, dif
> FROM
> (SELECT
> `Timestamp`,
> IF(@mac = `Mac`, `ResetCount` - @count, -1) as  dif,
> @count := `ResetCount` as Resetcount,
> @mac := `Mac` as mac
> FROM
> (SELECT 
>     timestamp AS Timestamp,
>     JSON_KEYS(qoeFlaps, '$.rgFM') AS Mac,
>     JSON_EXTRACT(qoeFlaps, '$.rgFM.*') AS ResetCount
> FROM
>     ptdata.qoe_cmts_details
> WHERE
>     timestamp BETWEEN '2022-03-22 10:00:00' AND '2022-03-22 11:00:00' ORDER BY `Mac`,`Timestamp`) t1
> ,(SELECT @mac := '', @count := 0) t2) t3
> WHERE dif >= 0
> ORDER BY  `Timestamp` ASC
> ```
>
> ```
> SELECT command denied to user 'u_1973485473'@'localhost' for table 'qoe_cmts_details'
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e52bb62ff53854de8080ad4520e78257)*

Comment: Hi nbk, mysql is still at 5.7 and we can't upgrade that to 8.0. it would be nice if we could but unfortunately no. Columns Mac and ResetCount are actually from a json columns. I've put my original query above.

Comment: @AlexTulio i added as mysql 5.7 Version one with the sample data and the second what you need in your code